# Piping nodejs output to file doesn't capture execution halting error

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a nodejs script which I'm running from the terminal like so:

```
node myscript.js
```

`myscript.js` contains this:

```
for (var i = 0;i < 3;i++){console.log(i);}

throw "Some error";
```

It output this:

```
0
1
2

/path/myscript.js:3
throw "Some error"
^
Some error
```

When I instead run it like this:

```
node myscript.js >> logfile.txt
```

And `cat logfile.txt`, I only get this output:

```
0
1
2
```

This is happening on an Alpine Docker container, but I've tried it on raspbian, and Linux Mint with the same result.

How can I get the error message (the thing I most want logged) to be stored in my logfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only redirecting [`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) to the file. If you also  want to have the errors [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) in the file, you need to redirect that also.

`node myscript.js 2>&1 >> logfile.txt`

You could also capture errors in a separate file:

`node myscript.js >> logfile.txt 2>> errors.txt`

Comment: The log file is still missing errors using the first command.

Comment: I used this command to achieve what I wanted, based on your post: `node myscript >> logfile.txt 2>> logfile.txt`.  Thanks.